# JQuery + Page Methods: Method is Never Called

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagemethods

I am just starting to mess around with Page Methods and jQuery together with not much success.

Below is my sample code...

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string test()
{
     return "testing 123";
}
```

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#Result").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/test",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If I set a breakpoint at 'return "testing 123";' it never gets hit, also when I try doing http://localhost/default.aspx/test I get the whole page posted back, same with the jQuery function.

I have also tried using scriptmanager and MS AJAX PageMethods.test(); with the same exact result.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out and it had nothing to do with JQuery or PageMethods... I have a URL Rewriter that's intercepting and redirecting and killing whatever is getting POSTed.

Thanks all for the help!
-Goosey

Answer (score 1):

just tried what you're doing with a separate file and everything works ok.

do you have a "scriptmanager" on your page? try removing it.  Pagemethods/jQuery ajax work perfectly without it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but try changing your type from a POST to a GET.  If you're going to http://localhost/default.aspx/test in your browser and it's working then you know it's working for a GET operation because that's what your browser is doing.

Comment: It's kind of strange, it seems both methods produce the same result. The $.ajax call will return with data, but it's the whole page.

So if I did http://localhost/default.aspx/test in my browser it would return the whole default.aspx page content... but the same happens if i just do http://localhost/default.aspx/doesntexist123123

Comment: @Goosey In that case I would suggest putting the webmethod inside an actual service (.asmx extension)  See what that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

Theres some good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288850/how-to-return-json-from-a-2-0-asmx-web-service).  Also [here](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Also, I don't know if it matters, but try making an actual web service page and putting the method in there, i.e. one with an .asmx extension.

Comment: TY for the quick response.

I did research both of those pages before I posted here.
If I use a web service instead of PageMethods it does work, and I can get it to return in either XML or JSON. Just wanted to get the PageMethods Version working.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check that your targeted elements (#result) are not refreshed using UpdatePanels, otherwise you can use the live functionality like that:

```
$("#Result").live("click", function() { 
  ...
});
```

Then, is your jquery code inside the same page as the Page Method ?

Comment: the #Result div does exist. And using FireBug (net panel) I can see that it's POSTing and getting a response from the default.aspx/test url. It's just the entire page and not my return "test"; string. Also if I set a breakpoint there, it's never hit.

Comment: Sorry almost missed the 2nd half of your question. My JQuery code is inside a seperate .js file. the C# WebMethod is in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the technique detailed [here](http://www.junasoftware.com/blog/using-jquery-ajax-and-page-methods-with-a-asp.net-webservice.aspx).

I set my data:

```
var contactData = "{'name':'" + txtName.val() + "',
                    'company':'" + txtCompany.val() + "',
                    'email':'" + txtEmail.val() + "'}";
```

Have my success method defined:

```
function success(result)
{
   alert(result.d);
}
```

Then call

```
`$.pageMethod("ContactUs/SendContactUsEmail", contactData, success);`
```

Job's a goodun.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs when you use PageMethods in combination with URL Routing. You can solve it by setting the url manually (in javascript):

```
PageMethods.set_path('/pagename.aspx');
```