# Most current implementation methods for serializing objects in .NET (as of v4.0)

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization, binary-serialization

I have an simple custom object called `MyObject` (a couple of basic properties and a `List(of MyObject)`, so it's recursive) that I need to serialize for storage. I'm not sure if I'll serialize to XML or Binary yet, but I want to make sure I'm using the most up-to-date methods for doing it, as there are a few different namespaces involved and I might be missing something.

- To do XML, I'd use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`
- To do binary, I'd use `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter`

There's also a `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter`, but MSDN claims it's depreciated in favor of BinaryFormatter. I would have expected everything to be in the second namespace above - is there a newer version of the XmlSerializer that I should be using?

Comment: The question is subjective. Different serializers are for different purposes. Do you want deep serialization? Do you want to interop with non-CLR languages?

Comment: @Justin Dearning: My intent isn't really to ask for the "best" method in a subjective sense, but really to ask about the most current implementations for each type. I didn't want to continue using a deprecated or replaced implementation when a newer one was available in another namespace. Since I found what appeared to be the most current in different namespaces above (I'd expect them together), that's what prompted my question. Perhaps I can clarify the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the correct, current implementations for serialization.

The XMLSerializer is in the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace instead of the System.Runtime namespace - I suspect this is because of its location (in the System.XML.dll assembly) and its dependencies on the `System.Xml` namespace in general.

Also, FYI - when there are newer versions of a class that are to be used in favor of older versions, MSDN flags them as "Obsolete".  For example, see [XmlDataDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument.aspx)'s help - the first line is:

> Note: This API is now obsolete.

Comment: I realize I'm targeting .NET 2.0, even though the answer seems to be the same for 4.0. Nothing has changed in the last few years with regards to these methods?

Comment: @rwmnau: Nope.  The link I posted was .NET 4 - though you'll see in .NET 2 that link was the appropriate class.  Luckily for you, in this case, you'll be using the same API that is current in .NET 4.

Comment: I mean that I'm targeting 2.0, and the namespaces I've referred to in my question appear to still be the best choice, since I assume that by "still current" you mean "as of 4.0, they're still the right choice". In any case, thanks for the affirmation - I was concerned that I was missing a much better choice somewhere in this gigantic framework...

Comment: @rwmnau: Yes.  The APIs listed are the best choice for those specific serialization forms in both .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 (and 3.5!).

Answer (score 2):

There is also DataContractSerializer, which is as of .NET 3.5.  It has some improvements over XmlSerializer in a several areas.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For JSON serialization, you can use:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

...

JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(PocoObject);
```

I had some difficulty getting this to work smoothly in .NET 2.0.  See my answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723639/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-asmx-web-service-created-in-vs-2005-to-receive-and-retur/2724283#2724283).