# jQuery + Webservices: Webservice not returning JSON, only XML

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, web-services

Looks like it just doesnt want to work...

@ Webservice:

```
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=False, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json), WebMethod()> _
    Public Function LoginDB(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
        global.user = user
        global.pass = pass
        If (<<lots of code to check if user is valid>>) Then
            Return "1"
        Else
            Return "0"
        End If
    End Function
```

The webservice DOES work, if the user is valid, returns 1 otherwise 0. But I always get it as XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"0"</string>
```

@Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Services/Autenticacao.asmx/LoginDB",
                data: "{'user':'ale','pass':'123'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
.....
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You need to post your jQuery, but are you using the getJson jQuery method? If not you need to explicitly set the correct data type:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/WebMethodName",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Or use the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method:

```
$.getJSON('WebService.asmx/WebMethodName', function(data) {
    //Do something with JSON response (data)
});
```

Comment: jQuery always returns "null"
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Services/Autenticacao.asmx/LoginDB",
                data: "{'user':'ale','pass':'test'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },

All i get is "null"

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the web method? If so what is the result before it is returned?

Comment: What do you mean? The webservice works fine, i just have no clue why its returning XML instead JSON, it's most likely ASP.NET problem...I just dont understand why the hell I'm getting a XML. all jQ returns me is "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

If you want your webservice to return JSON

asked and answered... [How to return JSON from a 2.0 asmx web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288850/how-to-return-json-from-a-2-0-asmx-web-service)