# unexpected token < when calling asp.net remote webservice .asmx using ajax() and jsonp

Tags: c#, ajax, vb.net, web-services, jsonp

I have a very basic - for testing - ASP.net Web service (2.0 and IIS 6.0) written in VB running on a remote server

**WEB SERVICE**

```
 <WebService(Namespace:="CMS_ChecklistSystemWebService")> _
 <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
 <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
 <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
 Public Class CMS_ChecklistSystemWebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function
```

**CONFIG.**

i had to add these following lines to my `webservice` config in order to be able to run the `webservice` in a Browser

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

**WEB SERVICE OUTCOME **
[image]

I was trying to call this `web service`  from `PHP` page using `AJAX` `JQUERY` running `XAMPP v3.1`

**JQUERY**

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.25.11/link to web service",
            data: "",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

**ERROR**

Following is how my console looks like after calling the `ajax()` function 
[image]

FYI if i click on the link in the second line it will link you to the `webservice` and run it as in the first image

**NOTICE**

if i use the same `webservice` from the same project - domain - i can easily do `ajax()` call and `type='json'` and it works perfectly with no errors

**Question**

- What i'm doing wrong ?
- Do i need to make the `Webservice` return a `JSON` object instead of `XML` if yes then how

Comment: The web service needs to return valid JSON surrounded by the appropriate jsonp callback

Comment: then how all i found is adding <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _ to the web service and it didn't work

Comment: it's clear there is nothing in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, you are specifying content type as json in ajax call. But, your web service is returning xml.

So, either you can specify content type as xml in ajax call and process the xml (I am not sure whether it is possible or not), or you can configure web service to return json.

Refer this SO question ([How to return JSON from a 2.0 asmx web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288850/how-to-return-json-from-a-2-0-asmx-web-service)) to configure web service to return json.

Answer (score 0):

Rumit has, I think, only given part of the answer here.  You certainly need to set your web service to return JSON instead of XML.

However, you've stated that you're setting `dataType: "jsonp"`  This requires that you return your JSON inside a method call with the name of the method being the value of the `callback` key in your second image above.

for example, it would look something* like this :

```
jQuery1910366312976758182({data: "Hello World"})
```

*not exactly, but step through and you'll get the idea...