# Call javascript function from asmx

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asmx

I want to return javascript function from asmx as string like following..

All html tags return but **checkNewMsg** variant **'script tag'** doesnt return! 
What happens really ?

Please advice

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getWindow(FromUserID, UserID, PerID, UserName) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TestMessageService.asmx/OpenWindow",
            data: "{'FromUserID': '" + FromUserID + "', 'ClickedUserID': '" + UserID + "', 'ClickedPerID': '" + PerID + "', 'ClickedUserName': '" + UserName + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var msgs = response.d;

                $('#div_Panel').append(msgs).fadeIn("slow");

                var elements = $('.panelContent');
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].scrollTop = elements[i].scrollHeight;
                }
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                $('#div_Panel').text(msg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string OpenWindow(string FromUserID, string ClickedUserID, string ClickedPerID, string ClickedUserName)
{ 
    string checkNewMsg = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.setInterval(fc_" + ClickedUserName.Replace(" ", "") + ", 10000); function fc_" + ClickedUserName.Replace(" ", "") + "() { alert('" + ClickedUserName + "'); }</script>";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(checkNewMsg + "<div class=\"ch_Box\">");
    sb.Append("<div class=\"ch_Header\">");
    sb.Append("<div style=\"float:left;margin-top: 9px;margin-left: 8px;\"><img src=\"Images/Status.png\"></div>");
    sb.Append("<div id=\"roomUsers\" class=\"ch_HeaderItem\">" + ClickedUserName + "</div>");
    sb.Append("<div onclick=\"closePanel(this)\" style=\"width: 23px; height: 27px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; margin-left: 232px;\"><img style=\"height: 20px; margin-top: 4px;\" src=\"Images/close.png\"></div>");
    sb.Append("<div id=\"cont_" + ClickedUserID + "\" class=\"panelContent\">" + FillMessages(roomID, FromUserID.ToInt()) + "</div>");
    sb.Append("<div class=\"ch_Text\">");
    sb.Append("<input id=\"msg_" + FromUserID + "_" + ClickedUserID + "_" + ClickedPerID + "_" + roomID + "\" type=\"text\" class=\"inp\" onkeypress=\"PushText(this)\" autocomplete=\"off\" /></div>");
    sb.Append("</div></div>");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I would like ask you... why do you use Json as response format and then inject a bunch of HTML? emit data then format that data in your client

Comment: Because there are so many cont_(**id(id from db)**) div and i must know which div reqiure js function.

Comment: obviously this not solve the specific question, but in my opinion you try to turn a screw with a hammer :)

Comment: I will try something, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why doesn't return script tag an asmx but when i remove the tag and then in the js side while i add script' tag before return value the problem is solved.

Just like this;

In asmx side;

```
string checkNewMsg = "window.setInterval(fc_" + ClickedUserName.Replace(" ", "") + ", 10000); function fc_" + ClickedUserName.Replace(" ", "") + "() { alert('" + ClickedUserName + "'); }#func#";
```

In Js Side;

```
 success: function (response) {
                var msgs = response.d;
                var arrCont = msgs.split('#func#');
                var MsgCont = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + arrCont[0] + "<\/script>";
```