# JSON Results Returning In XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, web-services

I try to make a JSON web service with use asp.net 3.5 and the result returning in xml like this :

```
<string xmlns="http://.../">
[{"HatId":9,"HatAdi":"SARISU - GÜZELOBA","LevhaAciklama":"KL08"}]
</string>
```

I used that [LINK](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/web-service-in-Asp-Net-part-4/) example and I realized that sample also returning as a xml.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HatlarJSON(String HatAdi)
    {

        Hatlar[] allRecords = null;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source="ip";Initial Catalog="";User Id="";Password="";Integrated Security=False");
        con.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var list = new List<Hatlar>();
                while (reader.Read())
                    list.Add(new Hatlar { HatId = reader.GetInt32(0), HatAdi = reader.GetString(1), LevhaAciklama = reader.GetString(2) });
                allRecords = list.ToArray();
            }
        }


        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(allRecords);


    }
```

How can I return the solution with no xml ?

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void HatlarJSON(String HatAdi)
    {

        Hatlar[] allRecords = null;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source="ip";Initial Catalog="";User Id="";Password="";Integrated Security=False");
        con.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var list = new List<Hatlar>();
                while (reader.Read())
                    list.Add(new Hatlar { HatId = reader.GetInt32(0), HatAdi = reader.GetString(1), LevhaAciklama = reader.GetString(2) });
                allRecords = list.ToArray();
            }
        }

Context.Response.Write( Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allRecords));
      //this is what I'm using


Context.Response.Write( JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(allRecords)); //your code


    }
```

Your **webmethod** contains string type so it will try to return string as response. so, we need to send response as an object.

I also had a same problem

Found solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392932/2630817

Comment: Thank you. Where is obj[0] came from or defined ?

Comment: @HaroldWren its just an example you can write your own. its just an object which I was using